# Layout messup in personal favourites view

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

After unstarring a question in the 'favourites' view of photo.SE, that view is now optically messed up:

[image: messed up favourites view]

Closing and reopening Firefox didn't help, neither did viewing the page in Google Chrome or waiting a few minutes.

*(and since we're on jeopardy, here's the obvious question:)*

Could this get fixed?

Comment: Looks like giving `#favorites-table` a `clear:both` brings it closer to what it's supposed to be. Couldn't figure out what's causing the float offset though.

Comment: Ah, the `line-height` on `h1#user-displayname` is the problem. Hopefully Jin or someone will be able to patch that up soon.

Comment: which version of FF are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this in FF 3.6.17

Answer (score 2):

The fix should be in the next deployment.